# Angular, Material Design Dialog component

Tags: angular, dialog, angular-material, lazy-loading, angular6

I'm Trying to create a Google material design Dialog component & load dynamically a "XYZ" component inside it.

When this module (which has imported MatDialogModule) is lazy loaded,
Angular keep yellings **"No component factory found for DynamicComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?"**
although "XYZ" component was added to entryComponents list of the **lazy** loaded module.

This error is not raised when module is **eagerly** loaded.

Any idea what I'm missing?

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "6.0.0",
"@angular/cdk": "6.0.1",
"@angular/common": "6.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "6.0.0",
"@angular/core": "6.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "6.0.0",
"@angular/http": "6.0.0",
"@angular/material": "6.0.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "6.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.0.0",
"@angular/router": "6.0.0",
"@ngrx/store": "^6.0.1",
"ag-grid": "18.0.1",
"ag-grid-angular": "18.0.1",
"bootstrap": "4.1.1",
"core-js": "2.5.6",
"font-awesome": "4.7.0",
"ng4-click-outside": "1.0.1",
"rxjs": "6.1.0",
"rxjs-compat": "6.1.0",
"zone.js": "0.8.26"
```

},

Comment: can you add your feature lazy module code and app.module code

Answer (score 2):

kindly check if your *DynamicComponent* is declared both in your **declarations** and **entryComponents** in the app.module.ts

Comment: If I do that, I will have to import the lazy loaded module in app.module , which no longer would be lazy loaded.

Am I right? :-|